# here is my unlink code to delete a image out of the server folder it is working but it deletes the news image in the folder

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

here is my unlink code to delete a image out of the server folder it is working but it deletes the news image in the folder and not the one that is associate with the image_id or the image_path so how do I tell it to delete the image for the image_id or image_path?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $res = mysql_query("select * from record_images where image_id=image_id");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $image_name = $row["image_path"];
        }
        unlink($image_name);
    }
?>
```

Here is my new code and it works good. OOPS I made a mistake it will delete the images that are associated to the image_id but it deletes the images in the server folder too soon when I click on the link in the Edit page it sends me to the Delete page and it will delete the image at that time and thin I have to click the Delete button to delete the criteria for that image_id in the database and I don't want that to happen. I don't want the image in the server folder to be delete until I click the Delete button in the Delete page

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['image_id']))
 {
   $res=mysql_query("SELECT * From record_images where image_id=".$_GET['image_id']);
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $image_name=$row["image_path"];
    $thnimage_name=$row["thumbnail_path"];
}
    unlink($image_name);
    unlink($thnimage_name);
}
?>
```

So here is my new new code. now it will delete the images in the server 
   folder when I click on the Delete button in the Delete page and not before. 
   and I had to add this image_id to the rest of the criteria for the Delete 
   button

```
<?php
    if ((isset($_POST['submit'])) && ($_POST['image_id'] != ""))
     {
       $res=mysql_query("SELECT * From record_images where image_id=".$_GET['image_id']);
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $image_name=$row["image_path"];
        $thnimage_name=$row["thumbnail_path"];
    }
        unlink($image_name);
        unlink($thnimage_name);
    }
    ?>
```

here is what my Delete button code looks like with the added criteria

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/finditlogit/private/sites/logs/artifacts/records/photo_gallery/delete.php?
    site_id=<?php echo $row_rssites['site_id']; ?>
    &amp;block_id=<?php echo $row_rsarchitectural_blocks['block_id']; ?>
    &amp;log_id=<?php echo $row_rslogs['log_id']; ?>
    &amp;record_id=<?php echo $row_rsrecords['record_id']; ?>
    &amp;image_id=<?php echo $row_rsrecord_images['image_id']; ?>
    &amp;site_criteria=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($site_criteria, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    &amp;site_attributes=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($site_attributes, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    &amp;block_criteria=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($block_criteria, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    &amp;block_attributes=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($block_attributes, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    &amp;logs_criteria=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($logs_criteria, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    &amp;log_criteria=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($log_criteria, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
    &amp;log_attributes=<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($log_attributes, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
    <input name="image_id" type="hidden" id="image_id" value="<?php echo $row_rsrecord_images['image_id']; ?>" />
    </form>
```

Comment: so what `$image_name` contains as a value and what you have into that specific folder as files? let start from there. also what `realpath($image_name)` returns?

Comment: the image_name refer to the name of the image in the server folder (uploads). the image name looks some thing like this 56423.jpeg or 34782.jpeg and so on the image_path is in the database and the image_path will look some thing this uploads/56423.jpeg or uploads/34782.jpeg and so on and each image gets it unique image_id

Comment: the image_id come from the edit page in the url  to the delete page where the recordset for the record_images table in the database is, and I have a Dreamweaver delete record server behavior and the button name is submit and it deletes the criteria for that image with that image_id

Answer (score 2):

Your query fetches all the records since you're saying `where image_id = image_id`.
Should the `image_id` be a variable or something?

The `$image_name = $row["image_path"];` will then be the value of the last record in the table, resulting in that image being deleted.

Comment: OK then how do I tell $image_name = $row["image_path"]; to delete the image that the image_id refer to?